# Python user input inside list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Hi I'm new to python programming and can't find this help anywhere

I have a user input value that I want to search for in a specified list exp :

```
option=input("option: ")

iplist=['192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.2', '192.168.1.254']

while option <= "3":
  #this is wrong. Help!
  nub = iplist[option]
  subprocess.call(["ping", nub])
```

I want The Option Of The User To Be The Number Inside The List For This program the output should be :

```
Option : 0

Pinging 192.168.1.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 2ms, Maximum = 2ms, Average = 2ms
```

Comment: Use `in` and youre good to go

Comment: `while int(option) <= 3:` and preferably `while int(option) <= len(iplist):`. And you'll notice that lists have a starting index of 0, meaning `3` will generated `IndexError` so you really want to do `while int(option) <= len(iplist)-1:`

Comment: Not sure if you need that `while` loop anyway

Comment: @Torxed `while int(option)  <  3:` or `while int(option) < len(iplist):` then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need a loop? Use `in` to check if the input value exists in the list and follow accordingly:

```
option=input("option: ")
iplist=['192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.2', '192.168.1.254']

if option in iplist:
   # do the rest
    pass
```

**OR**:

If you want to get the `Index` of the element in the list:

```
for index, elem in enumerate(iplist):
    if option == elem:
        print("Element found at Index: {}".format(index))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
option: 192.168.1.2
Element found at Index: 1
```

**EDIT 2**:

There are a couple of things to note first:

1. Take the input from the user and convert it to an `int` since you cannot access the list with str indexing:
2. I still do not see a point of loop

So:

```
import subprocess
option= int(input("option: "))    # 1
iplist=['192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.2', '192.168.1.254']

nub = iplist[option]
subprocess.call(["ping", nub])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Pinging 192.168.1.2 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.2:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

Comment: OP is trying to select a list index. Not a specific IP by the looks of it? so `in` won't work.

Comment: @Torxed That is what I guessed, edited.

Comment: Again, I think the idea here is to do `option: 2` and a IP should be selected.

Comment: Oh crap!!!! a moment please!

Comment: Don't stress it haha, good answers should take time. Not be hasted :)

Comment: yes the idea is to do option: 2 and an ip (here for example 192.168.1.254) should be selected

Comment: Uhm, Edit 2, guys?

Comment: @Torxed It Worked thank you!!